# Solutions of DGL-Systems at infinity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, fixed-points

I have a solution $H(t)$  for the dynamical system
$$\dot x = v(x)$$
with $v:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ a vector field and $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow \infty} H(t)=\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow -\infty} H(t)$.
Why trends $\lim\limits_{|t|\rightarrow \infty} H(t)$ to a fixed point?

Thank you!

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2159867/115115, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1594835/115115, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/585119/115115, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/246002/115115

Answer (score 0):

Consider that in
$$
H(n+1)-H(n)=\int_0^1 v(H(n+s))\,ds
$$
the left side converges to zero for $n\to+\infty$ while the right side converges to $v(H_*)$ where $H_*=\lim_{t\to+\infty}H(t)$.

Thus $v(H_*)=0$ which makes $H_*$ a fixed point.